# Quick way to make replica of container object

Tags: c++

I have container class which contains instance of another classes(with defined constructors) as member fields. None of all those classes doesn't contain pointer, everything is on stack. What is the quickest way to copy one instance of container class to another instance ?
(I wonder if there is quicker way that using copy constructor, also container contains instance  of std::map, cannot use c++11).

Comment: Please show what your containers look like, what you have tried, and what you think can be improved.

Comment: Quickest way is actually a copy constructor or copy assignment operator or if its pod then memcpy..